# Interactive Data Visualiation - Python

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, data-visualization, vispy

I've been working with data visualization using Python. To do such think, I've been using Matplotlib to get the visualizations. However, now I have some demand to provide more interactive visualization, besides a complete GUI.
I'm wondering how could I do such thing without losing all work done so far in Python, i.e., if there is some tool for Python to do such thing or if I have to go to D3 or something like it.
[Here](http://hefesto.ideias.inf.puc-rio.br/vsegura/VisualizingUncertainties/ui/exp/shepard/view.lp?experimentId=4) there is an example of what I have to achieve. I'm not building an web app, I just need to provide a good GUI and data interaction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: d3 would be a good solution if you're building a web app, but I think it would be hard to use with a regular python  script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as targeting a web app using frameworks as suggested by mwaskom, you could try data visualization / plotting libraries that offer more interactivity than matplotlib, such as

- [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/)
- [Pyqwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/gui-examples.html)
- [Glumpy](https://code.google.com/p/glumpy/)
- [Vispy (new project)](http://vispy.org/)
- [Galry](https://github.com/rossant/galry)

I've used PyQtGraph myself in several small projects.

Comment: Hi, @jmetz. Thank you for your answer. This packages is useful for building GUIs or to do such thing I should user another library? I have to provide both. Thank you.

Comment: `PyQtGraph` has included classes that will create the GUI for you, and pyqwt provides a qt widget which can be embedded in any Qt UI.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/) project, which aims to provide a translation between matplotlib graphics and d3. It's pretty new and rapidly developing, but it's worth at least keeping an eye on.

For a different approach, there's the [vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent) library, which has its own API but similarly produces d3 (by way of Vega) for making graphics that target the web in Python.